# Automatic Coding Style Checker, Hungarian style, C++

Tags: c++, c

I am looking for a C++ coding style tool that will validate a coding style. I have looked through the other SO posts, googled and tried some tools, but none of them meet my desired goal.

What I am trying to do is to check if variable names of a certain type have the correct prefix. All of the tools I have looked at so far, do a good job in indenting, identifying undesired spaces and similar things.

I need for example:

bool bMyFlag (correct) bool MyFlag (error, boolean variable does not have "b" prefix)

uint32_t u4MyNumber (correct) uint32_t MyNumber (incorrect, uint32_t requires "u4" as the prefix)

class CBottle (correct) class Bottle (incorrect, a class should have a "C" as a prefix)

Is there a tool that I can give a specific rule set for cases like this? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check list of coding style took here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C7752118043

See if any of tools there can supported your feature request.